# MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile always throws UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, memory-mapped-files

I realize .NET 4.0 is in Beta, but I'm hoping someone has a resolution for this. I'm trying to create a memory mapped file from a DLL:

```
FileStream file = File.OpenRead("C:\mydll.dll");
using (MemoryMappedFile mappedFile = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(file,
    "PEIMAGE", 1024 * 1024, MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadExecute))
{
    using (MemoryMappedViewStream viewStream = mappedFile.CreateViewStream())
    {
        // read from the view stream
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, no matter what I do, I always get an `UnauthorizedAccessException`, for which the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267557(VS.100).aspx) states:

> The operating system denied the specified access to the file; for example, access is set to Write or ReadWrite, but the file or directory is read-only.

I've monitored my application with Sysinternals Process Monitor, which shows that the file is indeed being opened successfully. I've also tried memory mapping other non-DLL files, but with the same result.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220913/unauthorizedaccessexception-on-memorymappedfile-in-c-4

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, I've got an example based on the above which runs without exceptions. I've made two important changes:

- I'm only specified `MemoryMappedFileAccess.Read` when creating the `MemoryMappedFile`. You've opened it for read, so you can only read. I haven't tried fixing it to allow execute as well by changing how the `FileStream` is opened.
- I've made the `CreateViewStream` call explicitly use `MemoryMappedFileAccess.Read` as well. I'm not sure why it doesn't use the existing access rights by itself, but there we go.

Full program:

```
using System.IO;
using System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        FileStream file = File.OpenRead("Test.cs");
        using (MemoryMappedFile mappedFile = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile
               (file, "PEIMAGE", file.Length, MemoryMappedFileAccess.Read, null, 0, false))
        {
            using (var viewStream = mappedFile.CreateViewStream
                   (0, file.Length, MemoryMappedFileAccess.Read))
            {
                // read from the view stream
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That code works for me, as well. However, what I'm trying to do is get the DLL loaded into memory as if it were about to be executed, so I can avoid doing all of the PE section mapping myself when reading the DLL's export table. For this, I need to map the file with ReadExecute access. But there doesn't appear to be a matching FileAccess.ReadExecute or even a FileAccess.Execute flag for FileStream.Open().

Comment: Right. I'll see what I can do, but I think there's some distance between "I can't use it for this purpose" and "it's completely unusable" :)

Comment: Indeed. Perhaps I was a bit harsh in that regard. Actually, at the time, I didn't realize there was a difference between how a file is opened for Read access and for ReadExecute access. I thought it was simply a matter of how the file was handled **after** being opened. Thanks for the help, by the way!

Comment: No problem - I just wish I could help you with the ReadExecute part. It may be worth logging a Connect issue - or email the BCL team directly. MS devs have always been very friendly IME :)

Comment: @JonSkeet maybe I'm missing something but the only overload for `MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile` that takes a stream as the first parameter is `CreateFromFile(string path, FileMode mode, string mapName, long capacity, MemoryMappedFileAccess access)`.  Your answer will not compile.  Why did so many people upvote this answer, what am I missing?

Comment: @ArvoBowen: That doesn't have a stream as the first parameter. Did you mean `CreateFromFile(FileStream, string, long, MemoryMappedFileAccess, MemoryMappedFileSecurity, HandleInheritability, bool)`? That *also* wouldn't compile though, and I'm puzzled by it myself. I'm sure I wouldn't have posted that without running it. Odd.

Comment: @ArvoBowen: I've edited it so it does compile (and still executes without exceptions). I wonder whether I was building against a pre-released version of .NET that had an extra overload...

Comment: Thanks Jon!  Thought I was missing something big time with everyone voting it up.  I was like, "What is everyone smoking!".  ;)

Answer (score 7):

I had the same behaviour when calling the CreateViewAccessor(...) method.

Turns out, the error was only thrown when the size parameter exceeded the length of the file  (it's not the same behaviour as we're used to with streams where size is a maximum value, instead it appears to take the parameter as a literal and the result is an attempt to read past the end of the file).

I fixed my problem by checking that the size doesn't exceed the size of the open file.

Comment: In .NET 4.5.2, this misleading Exception is still thrown.