# Concurrent views of MemoryMappedFile throws UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I have a large text file (0.5 gig) which I need to parse over and over in different situations, as much as 40 times in a single method. Of course this is going to take a long time and I tried to work over the file faster by doing it concurrently. I understand that a `MemoryMappedFile` is great for handling large files and concurrency so I chose to use it.

Now, I'm concurrently creating two views of the file (the views are of two different parts) but while one view works great the other one throws an `UnauthorizedAccessException`. Here's the guilty code:

```
private void PartitionAndAnalyzeTextBlock(int start, int length)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Starting analysis");

    //Exception thrown here 
    using (var accessor = file.CreateViewAccessor(start, length, MemoryMappedFileAccess.Read)) 
    {
        char[] buffer = new char[BufferSize];

        for (long i = 0; i < length; i += 5)
        {
            accessor.ReadArray(i, buffer, 0, 5);

            string retString = new string(buffer);
            frequencyCounter.AddOrUpdate(retString, 1, (s, j) => j++);
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Finished analysis");
}
```

`file` is instantiated in this line:

```
private MemoryMappedFile file = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(path, FileMode.Open, "MemoryMappedPi");
```

Do you have any idea what would cause this?

Comment: This exception doesn't make any sense.  Work from the assumption that it is triggered by something environmental, like a malware scanner.  There is no way that you can allocate *two* 0.5 GB views in a 32-bit process, so start by asking for a lot less.

Comment: Exception triggered by the environment? I didn't know that was possible. Also, there are four views running concurrently that *total* 0.5 GB. Each is a quarter of the 0.5GB file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's maybe related on how you create your memory mapped file. Check the answer by John Skeet  on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570624/memorymappedfile-createfromfile-always-throws-unauthorizedaccessexception). MemoryMappedFileAccess.Read access is passed to the CreateFromFile method.

EDIT: As indicated by  the comments, the CreateViewAccessor method takes an offset and a size as parameters to determine which part of the file the view will access. If these values fall outside the actual size of the file, an UnauthorizedAccessException will be thrown.

Comment: I tried using the constructor that allows for `MemoryMappedFileAccess` with the following code:
        private MemoryMappedFile file =
            MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(
                new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read),
                "MemoryMappedPi",
                500000000,
                MemoryMappedFileAccess.Read,
                null,
                HandleInheritability.Inheritable,
                false);

Which hasn't helped. This also doesn't explain why this works on one thread but not on another.

Comment: I have tried to create 2 MemoryMapViewAccessor from same MemoryMappedFile in 2 different threads and I don't get any exception. Have you tried to pass the same values in your PartitionAndAnalyzeTextBlock method in both of your threads just as a test. If you pass parameter values that doesn't fit the size of the file in CreateViewAccessor, you will have a UnauthorizedAccessException.

Comment: I am amazed I didn't think of that. That was the problem, passing parameters outside the file... Just put that in your answer instead of in a comment and I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: I updated the answer with the real solution. Glad I could help.