# Xamarin MemoryMappedFile System.UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, memory-mapped-files

I want to use Xamarin as a Crossplattform UWP and MacOs app. I got an existing Service for the Backend.

One major Feature that I need is a memorymappedfile! (for inter process communication)

So I tried to create one in Xamarin Projekt - but the .net Service could not find the memorymappedfile.

After that I tried to created the MemorymappedFile in the .net Service:

```
var CustomSecurity = new MemoryMappedFileSecurity();
CustomSecurity.AddAccessRule(new System.Security.AccessControl.AccessRule<MemoryMappedFileRights>("Everyone", MemoryMappedFileRights.FullControl, System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow));

using (var memoryMappedFile = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew("test", 102400,MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWriteExecute,MemoryMappedFileOptions.None, CustomSecurity,System.IO.HandleInheritability.None))
     {
      var accessor = memoryMappedFile.CreateViewAccessor();
      accessor.Write(0, 42);}
```

Now Xamarin can find the MemoryMappedFile, but when I run into an UnauthorizedAccessException:

```
var memoryMappedFile = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting("test");
var accessor = memoryMappedFile3.CreateViewAccessor();
```

But another none Xamarin.Forms Project (wpf projekt) can Access this memorymappedfile with the same Code!

I hope some one can help me or tell me how to use a MemoryMappedFile with Xamarin.

My Xamarin App use Xamarin.Forms with .net Standard 1.4 and I installed NuggetPackage: System.IO.MemoryMappedFile to get Access to MemoryMappedFile Basics (without MemoryMappedFileSecurity() )

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnauthorizedAccessException on MemoryMappedFile in C# 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220913/unauthorizedaccessexception-on-memorymappedfile-in-c-sharp-4)

Comment: Its no duplicate! they got Problems with memorymappedfiles in .net apps - cause of: "trying to access memory beyond the Limits" or "needed to create the view accessor " as you can see i got an viewaccessor an in the memorymapped file i only write "42" into ... so maybe someone else can help?